# how to disable this lines in mousejoint

Tags: java, libgdx, mouse, box2d

I want to check if a input event occured inside a body, in my case, inside a circle. The solution that I'am playing with is using mousejoint to this, and my code is:

```
    public class GameScreen extends AbstractScreen implements InputProcessor {

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    private FPSLogger fps_log;

    private MouseJointDef mjd;
    private MouseJoint joint;

    public GameScreen() {
        super();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,0f);
        camera.update();

        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        fps_log = new FPSLogger();
        world = new World(new Vector2(0,0), false);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
            Ball ball= new Ball(world);
            ball.start();
            ball.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        }
        Wall wall = new Wall(world);
        wall.start();

        mjd = new MouseJointDef();
        mjd.bodyA = world.createBody(new BodyDef());


    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

        fps_log.log();
        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);  
        world.step(BOX_STEP, BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS); 

    }



    private Vector3 tmp = new Vector3();
    private QueryCallback query = new QueryCallback() {

        @Override
        public boolean reportFixture(Fixture fixture) {
            if(fixture.testPoint(tmp.x,tmp.y))
                mjd.bodyB = fixture.getBody();
                joint = (MouseJoint) world.createJoint(mjd);
                return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        camera.unproject(tmp.set(screenX,screenY,0));       
        world.QueryAABB(query, tmp.x, tmp.y, tmp.x, tmp.y);

        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is what happens:

[image]

Why? By the way, is this method (using mousejoint) the best to achieve what I want?

Comment: I guess I have to implement the touchUp method to eliminate the joint.

Answer (score 0):

I currently can't check the code but AFAIK you'd need to assign the result of `camera.unproject()` to some variable and then query that. Currently you're setting `tmp` to screen coordinates and then use the unaltered vector as world coordinates.

The solution might be:

```
Vector3 worldCoords = camera.unproject(tmp.set(...));
world.QueryAABB(query, worldCoords.x, worldCoords.y, worldCoords.x, worldCoords.y);
```

A few other hints:

- Check whether the camera correctly translates mouse/screen coords into viewport coords. If the viewport is scaled and you don't take this into account, you might get the wrong coords right at the start.
- I'm not that experienced with Box2D but in general I'd not do a AABB collisition but a ray cast (at least in 3D - in 2D with orthographic projections it would be checking a single point). In some cases a point-sized AABB (width and height are 0) might cause problems.